# Why my instance does not have a name

Tags: python, class

The snippet of code is below. I want my object name to be equal to element[0]. My scripts successfully generates the objects, but fails to 'name them' I cannot understand why.

```
master_inventory = []

def import_catalogue():
    with open("./catalogue.txt", "r") as raw_catalogue:
        for page in raw_catalogue:
            page = page.split('\r')
            for line in page:
                element = line.split('\t\t\t')
                element[0] = Antique(element[0], element[1], element[2], element[3], element[4], element[5], element[6], element[7], element[8], element[9])
                master_inventory.append(element[0])


import_catalogue()

print master_inventory[1]

>>> <__main__.Antique instance at 0x10980f320>

print master_inventory[1].sku

>>> A00001
```

Comment: Implement [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) on the `Antique` class.

Comment: Why do you expect your objects to have names? Did you implement any such functionality?

Comment: Okay got it! I'm new to this, never encountered __str__ before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the [`__str__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) function in the `Antique` class, so you choose how you want to display your object's name. *e.g.*:

```
class Antique():
    …
    def __str__(self):
        return "Antique({},{},{})".format(self.foo, self.bar, self.foobar)
    …
```

Comment: For this thing, I'd rather suggest to define `__repr__()`, however.

Comment: indeed, I did not state it in my answer because `__repr__()` is referenced from `__str__()` documentation.